# SQlite error while updating the table

Tags: database, sqlite

I am reading data from a table and updating into other table in SQLite. while reading it is not showing any error. But while it is updating it is showing error because the text i am going to update contains **"You're"** it is showing error for **'re**--> this apps' re. Any way to update with this special character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert another single quote after You' so that the text becomes "You''re"

http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

**A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the backslash character are not supported because they are not standard SQL.**